# How to assign one model's record to another associated record in active admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have an app which registers applicants as `Participants` and then assigns them to `Groups`. The two models are associated via `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.  There are other hanging models related to `Participant`, but they are not connected to `Groups`.

I'd like to be able to assign a `Participant` to a `Group` when I create a new `Group` in active admin.

My two models are joined through a join table called `matchups`.

My `Group` model schema is as follows:

```
    create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.integer  "participant_id"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.index ["participant_id"], name: "index_groups_on_participant_id"
   end
```

My `Participant` model schema is as follows:

```
    create_table "participants", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.date     "birthdate"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "street_name"
t.string   "city"
t.string   "state"
t.string   "zip"
t.string   "role"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.string   "gender"
   end
```

My active admin resources allow the following params:
For `Groups`:

```
    permit_params :id, :description, :participant_id, :student_detail_id, :volunteer_detail_id
```

For `Participants`:

```
    permit_params :id, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :email, :birthdate, :phone, :street_name, :city, :state, :zip, :role
```

When I got to create a new `Group` in active admin, the only field I am able to fill out is :description.

I'd like to assign the new group to one or more :participant_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write a custom form in `admin/groups.rb` to accept multiple participant_ids like below

```
ActiveAdmin.register Group do
permit_params :description , participant_ids: []
  form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Group Details' do
      f.input :description
      f.input :participant_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Participant.all
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I have a follow-up question: if I want the participants to show up using their first_name attribute, is this possible? I assume so but I have tried :participant_ids.first_name and Participant.first_name with no luck.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Replace second input line with this `f.input :participant_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Participant.pluck(:first_name, :id)`

Comment: That worked! Is it possible to put multiple attributes? When I use this solution, the :id attribute no longer shows up.

Comment: :id will be in hidden field and what do you mean by multiple attributes?

Comment: For example, if I'd like to add the :last_name or :gender as well, would that be possible? I've tried several variations but no luck

Comment: Display only,  just for clarification in the event there are several participants with the same first and/or last names- I found the gem pluck_all which does the trick but doesn't look very clean. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187697/discussion-between-uday-and-dbate).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post, so I'll ask my question as an answer and edit it later.

Can you check your server logs and see what data is being sent to the create action? If I had to guess, the `participant_id` is never being sent.